# Eclipse equivalent for IntelliJ IDEA's "Complete Current Statement" command (Ctrl+Shift+Enter)?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I've been using IntelliJ IDEA, now switched to Eclipse. And I'm looking for an equivalent of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut. In IntelliJ this completes the current statement by putting semicolon and goes to the next line. However, when I use this shortcut in Eclipse, it inserts line above the current line. How can I change the settings to match with IntelliJ?

Comment: Ctrl + Space might be of some help. It does not do exactly as you want though.

Comment: When you mean "complete current statement", do you mean the statement is already complete and you want to just insert the semicolon then a newline? (note: I don't use Eclipse)

Comment: In Eclipse, cant you just press *enter* to go to the end of the current statement and complete it?

Comment: @fge, if you check IDEA's keymap settings, it maps `complete current statement` to Ctrl+Shift+Enter: what it does is: adds semicolon formats the source of the current line and cursor goes to the next line... it is very convenient

Comment: I bet you mean Eclipse's, right?

Comment: in intellij, it adds semicolon and formats current row and goes to next line... thats really cool.. I would say eclipse is really bad if you know the taste of Intellij... now I feel like myself in a 'prison' :)

Answer (score 2):

Found an equivalent plugin for eclipse here

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/complete-current-statement-eclipse

Only issue I found so far is that it does not obey the code formatting rules. (I like placing curly braces on new line for if statements). Otherwise seems to be similar to the IntelliJ version.

Answer (score 1):

Is this Feature present in Eclipse ( at least even as a plugin will be fine ) . I use Ctrl+Shift+enter in IntelliJ a lot . Some of the things it will do are

1. if it is normal statement then it will format the current line and add semicolon ( also the cursor position will be end of the line )
2. if it is a loop/conditional like for,if etc
   if  -> if ([cursor position]) { } -> if() { [cursor position]}
   [ ->  means ctrl + shift + enter command ]
3. If statement is already completed then it will format the current line and goes to next line indented position.

people might think these things are very trivial/not important but only when you try to use this you will find how useful this small feature will be and how much you miss in eclipse .